# How to create field using variable name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I create a field in mongoose using a variable name? I've seen some ways to do it using .update(), but I was wondering if there was a way to do it when creating a new document

I have my schema like:

```
var summariesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  name: String,
  date: String
})
```

and my object:

```
var date = '2015-02-01'
var obj = {
  ios: 100,
  android: 500
}
var doc = {}
doc[date] = obj
var mongoDoc = new Summaries({
  name: 'John',
  type: 'person',
  date: date,
  $doc: doc
})
mongoDoc.save(function(err){
  if(!err) log('done')
  else log(err.toString())
})
```

But it only saves the fields 'name', 'type' and 'date'.

Can anyone tell me if its possible to do something like that and if so,  what am I missing?

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict (anyone want to write an answer for quick easy rep?)

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? Using a date for a field name like that is usually a bad idea.  Also, you can't start a field name with a `$`, so `$doc` isn't valid.

Comment: @Alex got it right, I wanted to add a field that was not specified in my schema. About the field name, its not a date, its a string representing a date ('2015-02-01')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it..
first part from @Alex is right, just change the schema strict property to false so I can add new fields to my mongo document. For the field name as a variable, I just first created my entire object and then create a new instance of the document:

```
var summariesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  name: String,
  date: String
}, { strict: false })

var date = '2015-02-01'
var obj = { 
  name: 'John', 
  type: 'person',
  date: date
}
obj[date] = {
  ios: 100,
  android: 500
}
var mongoDoc = new Summaries(obj)
mongoDoc.save(function(err){
  if(!err) log('Done.')
  else log(err)
}
```

Success!

## EDIT

Three years later ES6 syntax also allows us to do so:

```
var mongoDoc = await new Summaries({
  name: 'John', 
  type: 'person',
  date: date,
  [date]: { ios: 100, android: 100 }
}).save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your schema definition to

```
var summariesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  name: String,
  date: String
}, { strict: false })
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but one more question, how can I add a field and set the name of that field as a variable. e.g. I want to add the doc object and the name of the field and want to be the string stored in 'date' ('2015-02-01')

Comment: you could just do it the same as you have with doc - but use mongoDoc['some-string'] = doc - i think?